# Xamarin development. Tasks are completing to early. I need advice regarding threads

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

I have a method which I am using to enable a user to input time. I have set it up that once a button is pressed it opens a dialog. The user can then select the time, once the user selects the time it is meant to populate a textview however I have found that once the dialog opens the textview is assigned its default value of null. It doesn't wait.

When i have ran tests using Toast messages I can see that the underlying code does work however its the order which is messing me about.

Currently I have attempting to implement the await feature with no avail.

I have attached my code. thanks for any help or advice. I am reasonably new to c# and xamarin by the way.

```
        <<within on create>> 
      StartTimePickerBTN.Click += async delegate
        {
            OnCreateDialog().Show();


            StartTimeTV.Text = (await UpdateTime()).ToString();

        };

    private void TimePickerCallback(object sender, TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
    {
        hour = e.HourOfDay;
        minute = e.Minute;
    }

    public async Task<string> UpdateTime()
    {
        string time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hour, minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

        return time;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the call to `UpdateTime`, instead you are calling `.ToString()` on the `Task` that is returned, instead of the `string`.

Your event handler should do

```
StartTimeTV.Text = (await UpdateTime()).ToString();
```

Comment: Hello Jim thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't work. I have amended my question to show my current code. Any advice??

Comment: I attempted to rate your answer but i'm not a high enough rank so it wont show.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue however i'm sure its not the best way but i will post my code below.

The plus is now the TextView is populated at the correct stage and waits until user selection.

```
    Within OnCreate, Please note the bool is a class wide variable

      StartTimePickerBTN.Click += delegate
        {
            SelectStartOrEndTime = true;

            OnCreateDialog().Show();

        };

        EndTimePickerBTN.Click += delegate
        {
            SelectStartOrEndTime = false;

            OnCreateDialog().Show();
        };


    protected Dialog OnCreateDialog()
    {
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerCallback, hour, minute, false);
    }

    private void TimePickerCallback(object sender, TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
    {
        hour = e.HourOfDay;
        minute = e.Minute;
        UpdateTime();
    }

    private void UpdateTime()
    {
        if (SelectStartOrEndTime == true)
        {
            StartTimeTV.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hour, minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            EndTimeTV.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hour, minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }

    }
```